# Solr - Collection created error: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml'

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have Solr-7.2.1 running on a cluster of 32 linux nodes/servers (+ a node that hosts ZooKeeper). I wanted to create a collection with the following command:

```
[solr@node-n03 solr]$ curl "node-n03:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=web&numShards=32&replicationFactor=1&maxShardsPerNode=1&collection.configName=web"
```

Before that I uploaded the configuration into ZooKeeper using this command:

```
./server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost node-n01:2181 -cmd upconfig -confname web -confdir /share/solr-7.2.1/server/configs/web
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
    {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":32675},
  "failure":{
    "IP.IP.IP.56:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.56:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard13_replica_n24': Unable to create core [web_shard13_replica_n24] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.62:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.62:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard31_replica_n60': Unable to create core [web_shard31_replica_n60] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.106:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.106:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard4_replica_n6': Unable to create core [web_shard4_replica_n6] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.69:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.69:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard1_replica_n1': Unable to create core [web_shard1_replica_n1] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.66:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.66:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard8_replica_n14': Unable to create core [web_shard8_replica_n14] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.61:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.61:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard3_replica_n4': Unable to create core [web_shard3_replica_n4] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.104:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.104:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard15_replica_n28': Unable to create core [web_shard15_replica_n28] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.107:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.107:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard12_replica_n22': Unable to create core [web_shard12_replica_n22] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.109:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.109:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard23_replica_n44': Unable to create core [web_shard23_replica_n44] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.68:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.68:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard18_replica_n34': Unable to create core [web_shard18_replica_n34] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.90:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.90:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard19_replica_n36': Unable to create core [web_shard19_replica_n36] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.63:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.63:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard27_replica_n52': Unable to create core [web_shard27_replica_n52] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.96:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.96:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard20_replica_n38': Unable to create core [web_shard20_replica_n38] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.57:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.57:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard2_replica_n2': Unable to create core [web_shard2_replica_n2] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.55:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.55:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard16_replica_n30': Unable to create core [web_shard16_replica_n30] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.95:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.95:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard28_replica_n54': Unable to create core [web_shard28_replica_n54] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.108:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.108:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard22_replica_n42': Unable to create core [web_shard22_replica_n42] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.94:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.94:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard25_replica_n48': Unable to create core [web_shard25_replica_n48] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.58:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.58:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard14_replica_n26': Unable to create core [web_shard14_replica_n26] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.105:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.105:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard24_replica_n46': Unable to create core [web_shard24_replica_n46] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.73:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.73:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard32_replica_n62': Unable to create core [web_shard32_replica_n62] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.74:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.74:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard17_replica_n32': Unable to create core [web_shard17_replica_n32] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.59:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.59:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard21_replica_n40': Unable to create core [web_shard21_replica_n40] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.102:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.102:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard30_replica_n58': Unable to create core [web_shard30_replica_n58] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.111:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.111:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard29_replica_n56': Unable to create core [web_shard29_replica_n56] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.67:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.67:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard5_replica_n8': Unable to create core [web_shard5_replica_n8] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.60:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.60:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard9_replica_n16': Unable to create core [web_shard9_replica_n16] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.70:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.70:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard11_replica_n20': Unable to create core [web_shard11_replica_n20] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.110:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.110:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard7_replica_n12': Unable to create core [web_shard7_replica_n12] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.103:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.103:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard6_replica_n10': Unable to create core [web_shard6_replica_n10] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.97:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.97:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard10_replica_n18': Unable to create core [web_shard10_replica_n18] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server",
    "IP.IP.IP.77:8983_solr":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://IP.IP.IP.77:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'web_shard26_replica_n50': Unable to create core [web_shard26_replica_n50] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/configs/web', cwd=/share/solr-7.2.1/server"}}
```

When I look at `/share/solr-7.2.1/server/configs/web`, the folder exists.
I changed the permission to `777` to avoid any permission issues, but that didn't solve the problem.

*Any hint on what I'm missing here?!*

---

***UPDATE:***
If I used different configuration, everything works fine:

```
[solr@node-n03 solr]$ curl "node-n03:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=web&numShards=32&replicationFactor=1&maxShardsPerNode=1&collection.configName=techproducts"
```

I've also created a directory /configs (as indicated by the error) on every node and copied the 'web' configset files (/share/solr/server/solr/web) that I want to use for overriding the collection default configuration. However, this didn't solve the problem.

So, the problem is with the new configuration that I'm using, but couldn't figure out where exactly Solr wanted this solrconfig.xml file to be located and why it cannot see it!

The schema.xml is:

```
<schema>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
   <field name="url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
   <field name="text" type="mod" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

    <fieldType name="mod" class="solr.TextField" indexed="true" stored="false" >
        <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
</schema>
```

Comment: So what is the solrconfig.xml file located in `/share/solr-7.2.1/server/configs/web`?

Comment: In solrconfig.xml, you configure important features such as: request handlers, listeners, the Request Dispatcher for managing HTTP communications, parameters related to replication and duplication, etc https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/configuring-solrconfig-xml.html   How would this solve the problem?

Comment: Because the error message is `solrconfig.xml was not found` - adding an actual `solrconfig.xml` file with configuration of "important features" would probably solve the problem.

Comment: The `solrconfig.xml` file is a required part of the configuration, so you'll have to have one that defines the basic features needed. If you don't know what you want in your configuration file, you can start with the one from the techproducts example and edit it to your needs.

Comment: Probably, you are uploading the top level configset dir. Instead, you should upload the conf content only, that is, confdir should be /share/solr-7.2.1/server/configs/web/conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is as simple as follows:
The 'solrconfig.xml' file was located @ `/server/solr/web/conf/solrconfig.xml`
I have to move it to`/server/solr/web/` and then upload to `ZooKeeper`.